# Gem list doesn't show bundler after "Successfully installed bundler"

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

I'm trying to install a second version of bundler. The installation outputs success message, but the new bundler installation appears not to exist at all. How can I correct this installation?

```sh
# Use sudo because of *system* rbenv installation
sudo gem install bundler:2.1.4
# => Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4

# Check for existence of new installation, but only the old version is available
gem list bundler
# => bundler (default: 1.17.2)
bundle _2.1.4_ -v
# => can't find gem bundler (= 2.1.4) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
ls /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/
# => [shows bundler-1.17.2 but not any other bundler directories]
```

I am using a system installation of rbenv (not rvm). I'm not working within a bundle (nor within a gemset since I'm not using rvm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PATH` of the root user is likely not the same as the `PATH` of your current user. Therefore the `gem` command that root loads will not be the same as the `gem` command you load as a normal user. This makes `sudo gem install` save the gems into a different location (the location of the Ruby installation found in the `PATH` of the root user).

To fix this issue, the most straightforward solution is to force root to use the same gem command by giving it the full path:

```
sudo `which gem` install ...
```

Note the use of backticks. Using backticks this way, the command will essentially expand to something like:

```
sudo /some/path/to/the/user/ruby/installation/bin/gem install ...
```

To figure out if the `gem` command of root is different from your default `gem` command, you can do this:

```
# As normal user check output of this command
which gem

# ..and compare it to the output of this command
sudo which gem
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `sudo`. It didn't run `/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh`, and that's the file that has the following:

```sh
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

To get past the problem, run `sudo -i`, then run the `gem install ...` command in the new shell.